# What is the difference between AWS Lambda and AWS Athena?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I only used Lambda, not Athena, so it seems like they are very similar to me. Serverless and all.

What is the difference between `AWS Lambda` and `AWS Athena`?

Comment: have u gone through [this](https://medium.com/appgambit/serverless-from-aws-lambda-to-aws-athena-181745e949b1)?

Comment: @Praga_t  Wow, it really helped me a lot. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Aws athena is used to run SQL queries. 
whereas,
aws lambda is like a file or package you want to run when required. Itt supports many languages like python,java. You can also interact with different services inside lambda suing boto3 api.

Comment: Do you run SQL queries to the DB which is stored in AWS (Redshift, DynamoDB, etc)?

Comment: SQl queries can only run for structured database not NOSQL DB. So athena runs query for RDS not for dynamodb.

Comment: Just one more question :) Can you run Athena SQL queries on RDB which is only located in AWS? Can you run Athena queries on local DB or DB on other physical DB server?

Comment: No. You can only run it on rds in aws.

Comment: The latest feature of Athena is Federated Query which enable to run SQL queries on multiple data sources including on premisses https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/query-any-data-source-with-amazon-athenas-new-federated-query/